# Display two figures with figcaptions side by side html5

Tags: html

I am having an issue making a 2x2 image gallery with fig captions.

I would like something like this:

```
-----   -----
|   |   |   |
-----   -----
Text    Text
-----   -----
|   |   |   |
-----   -----
Text    Text
```

But what I get is:

```
-----
|   | 
-----
Text

-----
|   | 
-----
Text
etc...
```

Displaying the figures as block does not seem to help when figcomment tages are attached.

Another issue is, Id like it to still be able to stack to the 1x4 on smaller screens the way raw  tags sould would.

Answer (score 0):

Put your images inside a container `<div>` and use @media queries to set the width of the container. Set the image `<div>` width to the same width as the images. You will need to play around with the width settings to suit your particular images.

See an example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jim31415/GHjqk/).

```
<style>
    .container{width:600px;}
    .photo{width:80px; font-size:80%; text-align:center; vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;}

    @media screen and (min-width: 160px) {
    .container{width:160px;}
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 240px) {
    .container{width:240px;}
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .container{width:400px;}
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
        This is the caption
    </div>
.
.
.
</div>
```